# Trigger compiles but doesn't insert rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a TRIGGER  that when fired inserts the data into a another table with USER  and SYSDATE data.  The script but no data is inserted from the TRIGGER.

I'm running Oracle Server.

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

  CREATE TABLE dept1
 ( DEPTNO NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  DNAME VARCHAR2(20),
  LOC VARCHAR2(20)
 );

 CREATE TABLE dept1_shadow
 ( DEPTNO NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  DNAME VARCHAR2(20),
  LOC VARCHAR2(20),
  USER_ VARCHAR2(32),
  MODTIME CHAR(17)
  );

 INSERT INTO dept1 VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');    
 INSERT INTO dept1 VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');    
 INSERT INTO dept1 VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');   
 INSERT INTO dept1  VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'WASHINGTON (D.C.)');    
 INSERT INTO dept1  VALUES (50, 'MARKETING', 'BOSTON');


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER row_dept1_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON dept1

 FOR EACH ROW

 DECLARE

 MODTIME CHAR(17);
 USER_ VARCHAR2(32);

 BEGIN

 MODTIME := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE);
 USER_ := User;

 IF INSERTING THEN
 INSERT INTO dept1_shadow (deptno, dname,loc, user_, modtime)
 VALUES (:new.deptno, :new.dname,:new.loc,user_, modtime);
 END IF;

 END;
 /
```

I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a record **after** you created the trigger? What happened? Because I've got [a db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99555be553f03010030dcf2ee87d3d9d) which shows your code working, with the simple expedient of creating the trigger then running your insert statements.

Comment: @Bohemian's answer is correct for your immediate problem. Also: *please please please* folllow @Belayer's advice to store `modtime` as a `DATE`. You're headed for grief if you don't. Also note in the same answer that you don't need to declare variables for user and date; just use the Oracle functions.

Answer (score 6):

Move the insert statements *after* creating the trigger.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99555be553f03010030dcf2ee87d3d9d) says this is the obvious and obviously correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Possibility, there was no commit. If you ran in the order of the layout the inserts weer done before the trigger existed. Possibility, there was no commit.  
A couple suggestions:

1. Change the definition of modtime to DATE. Storing a date as a string eventually causes problems somewhere down the line.
2. Remove both local variables and just use USER and SYSDATE in the values clause.
3. Finally remove the IF INSERTING statement. You have defined a AFTER INSERT trigger, so that if statement will always be true.

So result:

```
create or replace trigger row_dept1_trigger
   after insert on dept1
   for each row
 begin
    insert into dept1_shadow (deptno, dname,loc, user_, modtime)
         values (:new.deptno, :new.dname,:new.loc,user, sysdate);
 end;
```

Comment: Good job pointing out that the date should be stored as a `DATE` type. I hope the OP follows it or else there will be new questions within days asking how to dig out of a "date stored as a string" problem.